# Dotnetnuke - How to call method in code behind with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, dotnetnuke, ascx

This is script

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function ajaxcall(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DesktopModules/Modules/Admin/City/AddCity.ascx/GetMethod",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ value: "Vinay" }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (value) {
            alert(value.d);
        },
        error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
    });
};
```

This is code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetMethod(String value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

When i call function from button. It show js alert `Ajax Error`

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Test" onclick="ajaxcall()" />
```

I was tried replace `/DesktopModules/Modules/Admin/City/AddCity.ascx/GetMethod` by `AddCity.ascx/GetMethod` but it still not work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a WebMethod from an ASCX usercontrol - IIS won't allow it. It must be in an ASPX page.

If you don't need any security, you can create a generic handler (.ASHX file).

```
public class CityHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var fn = context.Request.QueryString["action"];
        var newCity = context.Request.QueryString["city"];

        if (fn == "add")
        {
            // TODO: add city
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("OK");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Then change your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/DesktopModules/Modules/Admin/City/CityHandler.ashx?action=add&city=Vinay",
    success: function (value) {
        alert(value);
    },
    error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
});
```

Comment: thank you, i think it work for me. Thank for your infomations.